# add_image_size not working Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to set a custom post thumbnail size in Wordpress. I have followed the documentation, which is pretty simple. But somehow the image is always set to some default
size.

**In functions.php**

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('a',453,103);
```

When I print with `the_post_thumbnail('a');` 
the post thumbnails will have the height 103 (correct) and width 100 (wrong). Why is the `width` ignored?

Answer (score 0):

`add_image_size` has a fourth argument, `$crop`.  If set to true (hard crop), it'll force your images to be the exact size you specified.  See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Crop_Mode).

Comment: Did you test by uploading a new image?  I think WordPress crops the image when it's uploaded.  Not later.  And it won't increase the size of the image - does your original image have a width of at least 453 and a height of at least 103?

Comment: Yes and it crops it to 453x103 which I don't want to. If I omit the last parameter the thumbnail becomes like 100x103px. I want it to stretch it out in that case, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just add ,'' after 103 to leave THE last argument as null